# How to disable warning in Eclipse - 'Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized'

Tags: java, eclipse

When I compile thrid-party library a number of 'should be parameterized' warnings are generated. I know how to fix them but I do not want to so I tried to disable all warning/error in Eclipse. However, the warnings are still generated after every warning/error are disable. Please help.

Comment: This is because I do not want to modify any file from third-party library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You Can change the settings in eclipse:

1. Go to project properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings
2. Enable the - Enable project specific settings
3. Change warning to ignore.

Comment: Ahh... I forgot to deleted the warnings before rebuild.

Answer (score 23):

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` to a method, statement or method argument to suppress this warning.

As an example a common one in Eclipse plugins is:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class adapter)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the file: `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`

add:

`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.rawTypeReference=ignore`

Answer (score -1):

If you're not interested in the type of the class being modelled by the `Class` object, an alternative to suppressing or ignoring the warnings is to use the `<?>` notation as follows: `Class<?>`.

Comment: That wont work. If the class has been defined generically(bounded or unbounded) and if its used without generics then <?> won't help. Either use with type parameter or suppress/ignore warning.